# Average columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, average

I would like to average the columns in a dataframe in R that contains integer values and occasionally NA's.

The dataframe called CD6 (Climate Division 6) which is initialized with NA values to store the average values for all data belonging to Climate Division 6.  The rows are dates and the columns represent hours from 0 to 23.  The dataframe looks like this:

```
    > CD6

       Date       H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 ... H23
       1948-07-01 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
       1948-07-02 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
       1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
```

The dataframe called CA has the true values for all climate divisions ranging from 1 to 7.  The data frame looks something like this:

```
    > CA

       Climate_Division  Date       H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 ... H23
       6                 1948-07-01 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
       5                 1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   ... 2
       6                 1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   ... 2
       6                 1948-07-01 1  0  0  5  7  0  1  1  1  0  0   ... 0
       6                 1948-07-02 0  2  1  2  1  1  NA 0  1  0  1  ... 2
       6                 1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
```

I have a for loop coded that will iterate through the dataframe CA row by row and map out to the correct dataframe for the climate division (in this example CD6 for climate division 6).  A problem is that I don't know how many rows there are that belong to each climate division to properly take the average of it.

By looking only at CD6, I would like to obtain the average for each date at particular hour that disregards NA if true values are present and that the final answer is a whole number (ceiling of the value).  If all the hours at the various climate division have a value of NA, I would like to keep it as so as oppose to 0.  The end result should look like this for CD6

```
    > CD6

       Date       H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 ... H23
       1948-07-01 1  1  1  4  4  0  1  1  1  0  0   ... 1
       1948-07-02 0  2  1  2  1  1  NA 0  1  0  1  ... 2
       1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  ... NA
```

I don't know exactly how to go about this in coding it and having it proficient.  So any suggestions will be helpful and thank for your time.

Comment: can you paste output of `dput(CA)` here for us to reproduce your data?

Comment: how is average of 1 and 0 (for Climate_Division = 6 and Date = 1948-07-01 ) 1? Shouldn't it be 0.5?

Comment: geektrader -  you are correct it should be 0.5, however I put 1 as I took the ceiling of it in order to maintain whole numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is aggregate means by grouping over two columns of `CA` i.e. `Climate_Division` and `Date`. You can use built in `aggregate` function to do that.

```
> t <- 'Climate_Division  Date       H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10
+ 6                 1948-07-01 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
+ 5                 1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
+ 6                 1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
+ 6                 1948-07-01 1  0  0  5  7  0  1  1  1  0  0 
+ 6                 1948-07-02 0  2  1  2  1  1  NA 0  1  0  1 
+ 6                 1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA'
> 
> CA <- read.table(textConnection(t), header=T)
> 
> CA
  Climate_Division       Date H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10
1                6 1948-07-01 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
2                5 1948-07-01  0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3                6 1948-07-01  0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
4                6 1948-07-01  1  0  0  5  7  0  1  1  1  0   0
5                6 1948-07-02  0  2  1  2  1  1 NA  0  1  0   1
6                6 1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
> #Now that we have our data, we do aggregation of data and calculate mean over that using following command
> CAMeans <- aggregate(CA[,3:13], by =list(CA[,1], CA[,2]), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
> 
> CAMeans
  Group.1    Group.2  H0  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10
1       5 1948-07-01 0.0 1.0 1.0   3 0.0   0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0
2       6 1948-07-01 0.5 0.5 0.5   4 3.5   0 0.5 0.5 0.5   0   0
3       6 1948-07-02 0.0 2.0 1.0   2 1.0   1 NaN 0.0 1.0   0   1
4       6 1948-07-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> 
> #Need to change the names of grouping column back to what they were before
> names(CAMeans)[1:2] <- c('Climate_Division', 'Date')
> 
> CAMeans
  Climate_Division       Date  H0  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10
1                5 1948-07-01 0.0 1.0 1.0   3 0.0   0 0.0 0.0 0.0   0   0
2                6 1948-07-01 0.5 0.5 0.5   4 3.5   0 0.5 0.5 0.5   0   0
3                6 1948-07-02 0.0 2.0 1.0   2 1.0   1 NaN 0.0 1.0   0   1
4                6 1948-07-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
> 
> #Now you can subset CAMeans to get content for CD6
> CD6 <- CAMeans[CAMeans$Climate_Division == 6, 2:ncol(CAMeans)]
> 
> CD6
        Date  H0  H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10
2 1948-07-01 0.5 0.5 0.5   4 3.5   0 0.5 0.5 0.5   0   0
3 1948-07-02 0.0 2.0 1.0   2 1.0   1 NaN 0.0 1.0   0   1
4 1948-07-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: I am humbled.  Though in my defense, the question was slightly obscure.

Comment: geektrader - Thank you for your help.  I did not realize that the function aggregate can do that nicely for me.

Nathan - sorry for the confusion, I was trying my best to explain the complex roundabout way of performing this, but I apparently did not do so well.  Nonetheless, thank you for your help as well

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at what you want here so I gave 2 options: `rowMeans()` and `colMeans()`.

```
CA <- read.table(
header=TRUE, text='Climate_Division  Date H0 H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10  H23
6   1948-07-01 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5   1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 2
6   1948-07-01 0  1  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 2
6   1948-07-01 1  0  0  5  7  0  1  1  1  0  0 0
6   1948-07-02 0  2  1  2  1  1  NA 0  1  0  1 2
6   1948-07-03 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA')

CD6 <- data[CA$Climate_Division==6, ]   # Populating your data does not require a loop.

(CD6rmeans <- rowMeans(CD6[, -2], na.rm=TRUE))

#     1     3     4     5     6 
# 6.000 1.000 1.692 1.417 6.000 
t(CD6cmeans <- colMeans(CD6[ ,-2], na.rm=TRUE))

# Climate_Division     H0 H1     H2    H3    H4     H5  H6     H7     H8 H9    H10   H23
# [1,]           6 0.3333  1 0.6667 3.333 2.667 0.3333 0.5 0.3333 0.6667  0 0.3333 1.333
```